# 100, 200, 300... Are these "numbers in the hundreds"?

Tags: numbers

Let's say you were in a casino or something.

You want to bet 140 dollars, but they only accept 100, 200, 300, 400, and so on.

If I say, "The wager can only be in the hundreds", would that make sense?

Is there any other way to say it? I feel like I should use the word "minimum unit" or just "unit".

Answer (score 1):

The expression **in the hundreds** signifies any number **greater than 200** (and presumably smaller than **the thousands**. So it doesn't mean what you want to say.

I suggest that either **in units of 100** or **in round hundreds** would convey your meaning.

https://www.helpingwithmath.com/by_subject/place_value/rou_nearest100.htm

Comment: I would add **in multiples of 100** as another common way to express this, used with a similar frequency to **units**. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=multiples+of+100%2Cunits+of+100%2Cround+hundreds&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmultiples%20of%20100%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunits%20of%20100%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cround%20hundreds%3B%2Cc0)